# Renaming Rootviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

Here's another very basic question. Is there an easy way to rename the rootviewcontroler? Say I decided that I needed to add a page before the current rootview (splash page, mini data snippets from the main app, etc.) How hard would it be to create another rootviewcontroller? I guess you would just take the current one and edit out lots of stuff.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to rename it? The name has nothing to do with whether you can show a view before or use other viewcontrollers.

Comment: In my case, I just want to add class prefix to it. Why this needs to be so hard?

Answer (score 0):

Make a new viewcontroller for any view or set of views that manage different user experiences or tasks.  I have a root viewcontroller in most of my apps to handle transitions and provide a few global methods, and then a viewcontroller (VC) for my settings UI, another for my game, another for my high scores list, etc.

Adding new VCs are as simple as the first one you added.  If you are a bit timid about VCs, there are other classes that can keep some of the VC handling hidden in their code, like the Navigation Controller.

Please read up on VCs to see how they are intended to be used.  Here is [one](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-programming-spring-2009/id384233222).